# Why are async methods not working properly in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have a piece of code that doesn't work properly. I want to define a group of tasks that will fill a field. But these tasks are not done
I want to run the following code snippet

```
const tasks = [];
for (const space of results.data.querySpace) {
    let rows = [];
    // check rows
    if (space.rows) {
        // check component is enable or not
        space.rows = space.rows.filter(
            (item) => item.component.is_enable === true
        );
        rows = space.rows;
    }

    for (const row of rows) {
        // iterate over the components and fetch their list fields
        const component = row.component;
        let task;

        if (component.__typename === "Program_Component") {
            task = async () => {
                component.episodes = await getPrograms(
                    args.Copyright,
                    component.tag_name,
                    graphql
                );
            };
        } else if (component.__typename === "Episode_Component") {
            task = async () => {
                console.log("log") --> dose not run !!!
                component.episodes = await getEpisodes(
                    args.Copyright,
                    component.tag_name,
                    graphql
                );
            };
        } else if (component.__typename === "FullscreenBanner_Component") {
            task = async () => {
                component.episodes = await getEpisodes(
                    args.Copyright,
                    component.tag_name,
                    graphql
                );
            };
        }
        tasks.push(task);
    }
}

const test = await Promise.allSettled(tasks);
console.log(test);
return results.data.querySpace[0];
```

What is the problem, what should I do to fill the component field correctly?

Comment: FYI, the last branch of your if/else if/else if appears to be the same as the 2nd branch.  Probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you pushed in the tasks array are a bunch of function pointers.  You never called those functions, thus they never execute.

What you need to pass to `Promise.allSettled()` is an array of promises, not an array of functions.

You can change this:

```
tasks.push(task);
```

to this:

```
tasks.push(task());
```

So that you're actually calling the functions and then inserting the promise that they return into your array that you then pass the array of promises to `Promise.allSettled()`.

All of this assumes that `getEpisodes()` returns a promise that is settled when the underlying operation is completed.

---

Here's a little different approach to what you're doing:

```
const promises = [];
for (const space of results.data.querySpace) {
    let rows = [];
    // check rows
    if (space.rows) {
        // check component is enable or not
        space.rows = space.rows.filter(
            (item) => item.component.is_enable === true
        );
        rows = space.rows;
    }

    for (const row of rows) {
        // iterate over the components and fetch their list fields
        const component = row.component;
        let promise;

        if (component.__typename === "Program_Component") {
            promise = getPrograms(args.Copyright, component.tag_name, graphql).then(r => component.episodes = r);
        } else if (component.__typename === "Episode_Component") {
            promise = getEpisodes(args.Copyright, component.tag_name, graphql).then(r => component.episodes = r);
        } else if (component.__typename === "FullscreenBanner_Component") {
            promise = getEpisodes(args.Copyright, component.tag_name, graphql).then(r => component.episodes = r);
        }
        promises.push(promise);
    }
}

await Promise.allSettled(promises);
return results.data.querySpace[0];
```

Comment: It could probably be simplified even more.  Instead of wrapping all the function calls in new functions, just do `tasks.push(getPrograms(/*...*/))` directly.

Comment: @David - Yeah, I was going to suggest something like that, but they are assigning to the asynchronous result to `component.episodes` in their function so it requires a little more rewrite to make that change.